# ElasticSearch _update with script file not executing

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to invoke an external script using [ElasticSearch's _update api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates). It seems as though the script is never actually run, though. An equivalent an inline script does make the expected updates.

Any ideas as to why this might be the case?

---

The script looks like this:

*scripts/update_comments.groovy*

```
"ctx._source.comments+=new_comment"
```

My elastic query looks like this:

```
POST my_index/blog/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "script_file": "update_comments",
    "params": {
        "new_comment": {
          "name":    "Jon Snow",
          "comment": "Winter is coming"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Running a `GET /my_index/blog/1` returns the original document, not the updated one. Note that the `_version` number increments, although nothing changed.

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "blog",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 2,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Guy",
    "body": "This is a post",
    "comments": [
      {
        "name": "Foo bar",
        "comment": "Great article"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For testing, I set `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true` and ran the same query, just with an inline script:

```
{
  "script": "ctx._source.comments+=new_comment",
  "params": {
    "new_comment": {
      "name":    "Jon Snow",
      "comment": "Winter is coming"
    }
  }
}
```

And got the expected result:

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "blog",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 3,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "name": "Guy",
    "body": "This is a post",
    "comments": [
      {
        "name": "Foo Bar",
        "comment": "Great article"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jon Snow",
        "comment": "Winter is coming"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the quotes around the script. That's what I get for copying and pasting.

So instead of

```
"ctx._source.comments+=new_comment"
```

The script should look like:

```
ctx._source.comments+=new_comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is simply not saved in the right location.

As explained in the [file script documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-file-scripts), you need to save it into `$ES_HOME/config/scripts/` or if you want to save them in a different location you need to change the `path.scripts` setting in `elasticsearch.yml`.

Comment: It's saved in the right place, otherwise I'd get an error saying that it could not be found. I also see in the stdout that the script was loaded

Comment: Then this is not correct `config/update_comments.groovy` and misleading

Comment: Do you have `script.file: true` in your config?

Comment: Yes, that was misleading, I've updated the post with the script location. Also updated the config with `script.file: true`, but this does not seem to have had an effect. I was under the impression that file scripts are enabled by default, see [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-scripting.html)

Comment: "I've updated the post with the script location" `scripts/update_comments.groovy` is not clear either... Are you certain that the script is in `$ES_HOME/config/scripts` ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the first comment, I'm certain it's being loaded. Here is the standard out when I start elasticsearch: `compiling script file [/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.3.3/libexec/config/scripts/update_comments.groovy]`.